# Export data from SQL to ADLS using ADF as JSON

Tags: sql, json, azure-data-factory

I am trying to load data to ADLS gen2 from Azure SQL DB in json format.
Below is the query I am using to load it in JSON format

````
select    k2.[mandt],k2.[kunnr],
'knb1' = (select [bukrs] as 'bukrs' , [pernr]
           from [ods_cdc_sdr].[knb1] k1
               where k2.mandt=k1.mandt AND K1.kunnr=K2.kunnr
               FOR JSON PATH),
'knvp' =(select knvp.vkorg,   vtweg from  [ods_cdc_sdr].[knvp] knvp where  k2.mandt=knvp.mandt AND knvp.kunnr=K2.kunnr FOR JSON PATH) 
from [ods_cdc_sdr].[kna1] k2 
group by k2.[mandt],k2.[kunnr] 
FOR JSON PATH

For one or two records data looks fine but when I am trying to load 1000 and above records, json seems to be splitting also not in a proper format (below is the example)

**{"JSON_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B"**:"[{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000001\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000004\",\"knvp\":[{\"vkorg\":\"FR12\",\"vtweg\":\"01\"},{\"vkorg\":\"FR12\",\"vtweg\":\"01\"},{\"vkorg\":\"FR12\",\"vtweg\":\"01\"},{\"vkorg\":\"FR12\",\"vtweg\":\"01\"},{\"vkorg\":\"FR12\",\"vtweg\":\"01\"},{\"vkorg\":\"FR65\",\"vtweg\":\"01\"},{\"vkorg\":\"FR65\",\"vtweg\":\"01\"},{\"vkorg\":\"FR65\",\"vtweg\":\"01\"},{\"vkorg\":\"FR65\",\"vtweg\":\"01\"}]},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000006\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000008\",\"knvp\":[{\"vkorg\":\"FR13\",\"vtweg\":\"04\"},{\"vkorg\":\"FR13\",\"vtweg\":\"04\"},{\"vkorg\":\"FR13\",\"vtweg\":\"04\"},{\"vkorg\":\"FR13\",\"vtweg\":\"04\"}]},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000012\",\"knvp\":[{\"vkorg\":\"FR13\",\"vtweg\":\"04\"},{\"vkorg\":\"FR13\",\"vtweg\":\"04\"},{\"vkorg\":\"FR13\",\"vtweg\":\"04\"},{\"vkorg\":\"FR13\",\"vtweg\":\"04\"}]},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000015\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000021\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000022\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000023\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000026\",\"knvp\":[{\"vkorg\":\"IN14\",\"vtweg\":\"01\"},{\"vkorg\":\"IN14\",\"vtweg\":\"01\"},{\"vkorg\":\"IN14\",\"vtweg\":\"01\"},{\"vkorg\":\"IN14\",\"vtweg\":\"01\"}]},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000045\",\"knvp\":[{\"vkorg\":\"FR13\",\"vtweg\":\"04\"},{\"vkorg\":\"FR13\",\"vtweg\":\"04\"},{\"vkorg\":\"FR13\",\"vtweg\":\"04\"},{\"vkorg\":\"FR13\",\"vtweg\":\"04\"}]},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000046\",\"knvp\":[{\"vkorg\":\"FR13\",\"vtweg\":\"04\"},{\"vkorg\":\"FR13\",\"vtweg\":\"04\"},{\"vkorg\":\"FR13\",\"vtweg\":\"04\"},{\"vkorg\":\"FR13\",\"vtweg\":\"04\"}]},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000048\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000050\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000054\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000057\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000058\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000060\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000065\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000085\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000086\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000089\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000090\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000092\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000106\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000124\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000129\",\"knvp\":[{\"vkorg\":\"FR40\",\"vtweg\":\"01\"},{\"vkorg\":\"FR40\",\"vtweg\":\"01\"},{\"vkorg\":\"FR40\""}
**{"JSON_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B"**:",\**"vtweg\":\"01\"},{\"vkorg\":\"FR40\",\"vtweg\":\"01\"}]},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000149\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000164\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000167\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000174\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000178\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000181\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000185\",\"knvp\":[{\"vkorg\":\"FR65\",\"vtweg\":\"01\"},{\"vkorg\":\"FR65\",\"vtweg\":\"01\"},{\"vkorg\":\"FR65\",\"vtweg\":\"01\"},{\"vkorg\":\"FR65\",\"vtweg\":\"01\"}]},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000189\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000214\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000223\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000228\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000239\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000240\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000249\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000251\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000257\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000260\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000261\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000262\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000286\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000301\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000320\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000347\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000350\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000353\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000364\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000370\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000372\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000373\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000375\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000377\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000380\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000381\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000383\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000384\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000386\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000387\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000391\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000393\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000396\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000397\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000408\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000416\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000421\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000424\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000425\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000428\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000443\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000447\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000453\"},{\"mandt"}
**{"JSON_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B"**:"\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000475\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"0000000478\"},{\"mandt\":\"172\\",\"kunnr\":\"2100000001\",\"knvp\":[{\"vkorg\":\"Y200\",\"vtweg\":\"Z1\"},{\"vkorg\":\"Y200\",\"vtweg\":\"Z1\"},{\"vkorg\":\"Y200\",\"vtweg\":\"Z1\"},{\"vkorg\":\"Y200\",\"vtweg\":\"Z1\"}]},{\"mandt\":\"172\",\"kunnr\":\"2100000002\",\"knvp\":[{\"vkorg\":\"Y200\",\"vtweg\":\"Z1\"},{\"vkorg\":\"Y200\",\"vtweg\":\"Z1\"},{\"vkorg\":\"Y200\",\"vtweg\":\"Z1\"},{\"vkorg\":\"Y200\",\"vtweg\":\"Z1\"}]}]"}
Please help me how can I get entire message in a proper format```
````

Comment: Do you just want to save the result in json format in ADLS ?

Comment: Hi @haritha nuthi, I've updated my answer. :)

Comment: Hi @haritha nuthi, please correct me if I understand you wrong in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to save query result in json format to ADLS. You'd better remove `FOR JSON PATH`. We can use Azure Data Factory to generate nested JSON.

I created a simple test with two tables. Table `Entities` and table `EntitiesEmails` are related through the Id and EntitiyId fields. Usually we can use following sql to return a nested json type array. But ADF will automatically add escape characters '\' to escape double quotes.

```sql
SELECT
    ent.Id AS 'Id',
    ent.Name AS 'Name',
    ent.Age AS 'Age',
    EMails = (
        SELECT
            Emails.EntitiyId AS 'Id',
            Emails.Email AS 'Email'
        FROM EntitiesEmails Emails WHERE Emails.EntitiyId = ent.Id
        FOR JSON PATH
    )
FROM Entities ent
FOR JSON PATH
```

[image]

I researched out the use of data flow to generate a nested json array. As follows show:
[image]

1. Set source1 to the SQL table `Entities` .
   [image]
2. Set source2 to the SQL table `EntitiesEmails` .
   [image]
3. At Aggregate1 activity, set Group By `Aggregate1`
   [image]
   Type in expression **`collect(Email)`** at Aggregates. It will collect all email addresses into an array.
   [image]
   Data preview is as follows:
   [image]
4. Then we can join these two streams at Join1 activity.
   [image]
5. Then we can filter out extra columns at Select1 activity.
   [image]
6. Then we can sink the result to our json file in ADLS.
   [image]
7. Debug output is as follows:
   [image]

Comment: But I am trying for nested JSON, how can I achieve it directly in JSON

Comment: Can you use data flow in ADF?